# Get bindingContext of listview's page in DataTemplate

Tags: forms, xamarin, binding, command, datatemplate

I want to bind a button inside my DataTemplate (which is a viewCell) to a command of the page's viewModel (which is ofc the bindingContext's page) of the listView. 
I put the template in another file as I want to reuse it somewhere else this is the main prob
Here is my listView in my page.

```
  _timeLineListView = new MR.Gestures.ListView
            {
                RowHeight = 230,
                SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TimeLineScheduleComponent)),
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("0D2E383F")
            };
```

*ItemSource of listView is bound to viewModel's property*

Inside the TimeLineScheduleComponent, I got a button :

```
   _acceptScheduleButton.SetBinding(MR.Gestures.Button.TappedCommandProperty, "ToLastStepTradeCommand");
_acceptScheduleButton.BindingContext = ParentBindingContext;
```

And here is the page's viewModel with the command I want to bind to :

```
/// <summary>
/// Command schedule button
/// </summary>
public Command ToLastStepTradeCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(() =>
        {

        });
    }
}
```

I tried to add a bindableProperty inside my viewCell like this :

```
  public static BindableProperty ParentBindingContextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ParentBindingContext",
            typeof(object), typeof(TimeLineScheduleComponent));

        public object ParentBindingContext
        {
            get { return GetValue(ParentBindingContextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ParentBindingContextProperty, value); }
        }
```

And on the page I did this :

```
var test = new DataTemplate(typeof(TimeLineScheduleComponent));
test.SetBinding(TimeLineScheduleComponent.ParentBindingContextProperty, new Binding(BindingContextProperty.PropertyName));
test.BindingContext= this; //this is wrong I know ...
```

But doesn't work, Im doing something wrong with last part I think (which bindingContext should I give to my test dataTemplate ?). I'm on pure c# found some xaml solution but hard to translate.

Thanks.